# Updating location of circle with mouse movement breaks on fast mouse movement, tkinter-python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a draggable point(a circle). The code works, however, while dragging, if the mouse motion is quick the point stops moving. I have taken help from [this code](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-June/156242.html) for making this program. I will be using this point later on for other purposes. Here is my full code,

```
from tkinter import *
import sys,os,string,time

class Point():
    def __init__(self,canvas,x,y):
        self.canvas = canvas
        # It could be that we start dragging a widget
        # And release it while its on another
        # Hence when we land on a widget we set self.loc to 1
        # And when we start dragging it we set self.dragged to 1
        self.loc = self.dragged = 0
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = 5
        self.point = canvas.create_oval(self.x-self.radius,self.y-self.radius,self.x+self.radius,self.y+self.radius,fill="green",tag="Point")

        canvas.tag_bind("Point","<ButtonPress-1>",self.down)
        canvas.tag_bind("Point","<ButtonRelease-1>",self.chkup)
        canvas.tag_bind("Point","<Enter>",self.enter)
        canvas.tag_bind("Point","<Leave>",self.leave)

    def down(self,event):
        self.loc = 1
        self.dragged = 0
        event.widget.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
        canvas.itemconfigure(self.point,fill = "red")

    def motion(self,event):
        root.config(cursor = "exchange")
        cnv = event.widget
        cnv.itemconfigure(self.point,fill = "red")
        self.x,self.y = cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y)
        got = canvas.coords(self.point,self.x-self.radius,self.y-self.radius,self.x+self.radius,self.y+self.radius)

    def enter(self,event):
        canvas.itemconfigure(self.point,fill="blue")
        self.loc = 1
        if self.dragged == event.time:
            self.up(event)

    def up(self,event):
        event.widget.unbind("<Motion>")
        canvas.itemconfigure(self.point,fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()

    def chkup(self,event):
        event.widget.unbind("<Motion>")
        root.config(cursor = "")
        canvas.itemconfigure(self.point,fill="green")
        if self.loc: # is button released in the same widget as pressed
            self.up(event)
        else:
            self.dragged = event.time

    def leave(self,event):
        self.up(event)

root = Tk()
root.title("Drag and Drop")
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 256, height = 256, borderwidth = 1)
point = Point(canvas,128,128)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `<Leave>` binding can fire if you move the mouse outside of the tiny circle faster than you can process the move. That causes the binding for `<Motion>` to be disabled.

My recommendation is to a) don't bind on `<Leave>` to disable the binding, and b) bind on `<B1-Motion>` so that the binding is active only while the button is pressed.